# How to get month value using week value sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get month value using week no.
I have week numbers stored in a table with year value.

[image]

How to query database to get month value using that week value.

I am using SQL

Comment: what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Use [DateAdd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.110).aspx) function!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  SELECT DATEPART(m,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + CAST(t.year as VARCHAR(4))) + (t.week-1), 6))
```

Comment: I'd agree with this, although this has week starts on a Sunday which shows Week 6 as being in month 1 rather than 2 (2016-02-01 vs 2016-01-31)

Comment: I am getting this error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1/1/' to data type int

Comment: Now It works fine. Only thing you missed to close DATEDIFF()

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're classing your week numbers, For example, if we assume that week numbers start on a Monday then we'd have to say that week 1 in 2016 actually started on Monday 28th of December 2015 and finished on Sunday 3rd January 2016. If this is how your week numbers are set up then you can use the method below

Sample Data;

```
CREATE TABLE #DateTable (WeekNum int, YearNum int)
INSERT INTO #DateTable (WeekNum, YearNum)
VALUES
(1,2016)
,(2,2016)
,(3,2016)
,(4,2016)
,(5,2016)
,(6,2016)
,(7,2016)
```

We will then cast the week and year into a date, then convert this to a month;

```
SELECT
WeekNum
,YearNum
,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, '1/1/' + CONVERT(varchar(4),YearNum)) + (WeekNum-1), 7) AS WeekStart
,DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 7, '1/1/' + CONVERT(varchar(4),YearNum)) + (WeekNum-1), 7)) MonthNum
```

(Edit: updated as source is int)

Gives these results;

```
WeekNum YearNum WeekStart                   MonthNum
1       2016    2015-12-28 00:00:00.000     12
2       2016    2016-01-04 00:00:00.000     1
3       2016    2016-01-11 00:00:00.000     1
4       2016    2016-01-18 00:00:00.000     1
5       2016    2016-01-25 00:00:00.000     1
6       2016    2016-02-01 00:00:00.000     2
7       2016    2016-02-08 00:00:00.000     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't go from week number to month because weeks can occur in two different months. For example the 31st Jan 2016 and 1st Feb 2016 are both in week 6.

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '2016-01-31')
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '2016-02-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the query below:

```
SELECT 
    [Week], 
    [Year], 
    'Output-Month' = MONTH(DATEADD(WEEK, [Week], DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19050101', '01/01/' + CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))), '19050101')))
FROM YourTable
```

1st is to get the 1st day of the year using this:

```
DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, '19050101', '01/01/' + CAST([Year] AS VARCHAR(4))), '19050101')
```

2nd is to add your number of week using this:

```
DATEADD(WEEK, [Week], 'From 1st result')
```

Last is getting the number of Month using the MONTH function.